# how to add value to data-form-data and multiple using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I use `Django` and `JQuery`. Now I try to set up a form multi file input inside a `bootstrap modal form` using `JQuery`, but i struggle with `data-form-data` and `multiple` `probs`. I have checked every question but still I cannot find a solution.

```
$('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'file',
                        id:   'fileupload',
                        name: 'image',
                        class:'galler',
                        multiple,
                        style: "display: none;",
                        data-form-data: '{
                            "csrfmiddlewaretoken":"{{csrf_token}}",
                            "gallery_id", response.gallery_id
                        }'

                    }).appendTo('form#album-create-form');
```

This is my solution but I get an error message

```
(index):2713 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'
```

Can you guide me with correct usage?

ps: all the view and ajax code

class BasicUploadView(View):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    title = request.POST.get('title')
    gallery_form = GalleryModelForm( data=request.POST
    if gallery_form.is_valid():
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        galleryextended = GalleryExtended.objects.create(title=title, slug=gallery.slug, user_id=request.user.id)
        galleryextended.save()
        data = {'is_valid': True, 'title': galleryextended.title, 'gallery_id': galleryextended.id}
    else:
        data = {'is_valid': False}
    return JsonResponse(data)

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'galleries:basic_upload' %}",
            data: 
                {
                    title: $('#galleryTitle').val(),
                    csrfToken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },

            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#create-photo-album").modal('hide');
                openModal(response);

                function openModal(product_data){
                  let id = response.gallery_id;

                  $('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'file',
                        id:    'fileupload',
                        name: 'image',
                        class: 'galler',
                        multiple: 'multiple',
                        style: "display: none;",
                        'data-form-data': '{ "csrfmiddlewaretoken":"{{csrf_token}}","gallery_id": id }'

                    }).appendTo('form#album-create-form');


                  $("#update-photo-album").modal('show');
                };


            },
            error: function (response) {
                // alert the error if any error occured
                alert(response["responseJSON"]["error"]);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few issues here.

- The `multiple` property needs a value.
- Hyphens (`-`) in the data attribute are not valid syntax in JS, you need to wrap the value which contains them in quotes.
- `class` is a reserved keyword so it too needs to be in quotes.
- The comma (`,`) after `gallery_id` in the data attribute JSON value needs to be a `:`.
- The line breaks in the data attribute value are invalid given the string literal you're using. If you want to keep the line breaks in a string, use a template literal
- The `response.gallery_id` value needs to be concatenated to the JSON you put in to the data attribute

With that said, try this:

```js
$('<input>').attr({
  'type': 'file',
  'id': 'fileupload',
  'name': 'image',
  'class': 'galler',
  'multiple': 'multiple',
  'data-form-data': `{
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{csrf_token}}",
    "gallery_id": ${response.gallery_id}
  }`
}).hide().appendTo('form#album-create-form');
```

Comment: ok perfect, but gallery_id response.gallery_id value is not set now, how do I use the value of gallery_id? thanks for quick answer.

Comment: I just edited with an update to that, you need to use `:` there not `,`

Comment: yes i used :, but still it looks as "id" as a text. not the number

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to mean as you've given no indication of what the value of `response.gallery_id` actually is, nor how you intend to use it. All I can do is answer the question you posed, which is what this does.

Comment: ok I have added the json response and ajax I am using, If you have any idea how to place the value of gallery_id, can you take a look ?

Comment: Thank you. The problem is because you need to concatenate the value in to the string. As I've changed it to a template literal in the above example, it can be done even more simply. See the update. Here's the docs on how to use template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals